# MarkLogic SQL Collation not used

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am getting different results using XQuery and SQL using a **case insensitive collation**.

I've got two app servers, a http and a odbc server, configured. Both using the same  collation http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1, which should be caseinsensitive.

Following XQueries return the **correct** value:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
/table[column="Content"];
xquery version "1.0-ml";
/table[column="content"]
```

=> Both return the searched document.

Following SQL Query does **not** return the correct value:

```
select * from table
where column = 'Content';
```

But this does:

```
select * from table
where column = 'content';
```

Is there anything else i need to configure in order to use a caseinsensitive collation with SQL? (except having a odbc server with that collation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe MarkLogic indexes documents with a collation for the relational views.

If you are using templates to creates views of the documents you may be able to match the collations by setting collation property at `rows/row/columns/column/collation` in the template definition.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_81078

Comment: Dunno how i missed that! That's it ! Thanks a lot :)